# Undefined index: icon error , while running laravel seeder

Tags: laravel, migration, laravel-seeding

This is my code:

```php
DB::beginTransaction();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($privileges); $i++) {
        DB::table('prev_definition')->insert([
            'priv_title' => $privileges[$i]['priv_title'],
            'priv_key' => $privileges[$i]['priv_key'],
            'display_group' => $privileges[$i]['display_group'],
            'parent_id' => $privileges[$i]['parent_id'],
            'type' => $privileges[$i]['type'],
            'icon' => $privileges[$i]['icon'], // here is error
        ]);
    }
DB::commit();
```

I have added two new fields type and icon and when i run seeders it says:

```
In privilegesTableSeeder
Undefined index: icon
```

I dont know where is issue:

This is my array:

```php
['priv_title' => 'Basic Contact','priv_key' => 'can_access_patient_basic_contact', 'display_group' => 'patient_basic_contact','parent_id' => 7,'type' => 'menu'],
['priv_title' => 'Create Task','priv_key' => 'patient_basic_contact_can_add_task', 'display_group' => 'patient_basic_contact','parent_id' => 13,'type' => 'create_task','icon' => 'create_task'],
['priv_title' => 'View','priv_key' => 'patient_basic_contact_can_view', 'display_group' => 'patient_basic_contact','parent_id' => 13,'type' => 'view','icon' => 'view'],
['priv_title' => 'Edit','priv_key' => 'patient_basic_contact_can_edit', 'display_group' => 'patient_basic_contact','parent_id' => 13,'type' => 'edit','icon' => 'edit'],
['priv_title' => 'Delete','priv_key' => 'patient_basic_contact_can_delete', 'display_group' => 'patient_basic_contact','parent_id' => 13,'type' => 'delete','icon' => 'delete'],
```

Can you guys sort out this problem?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The first array element does not have an `icon` key to be accessed. If the icon database table row can be nullable and you don't want to set any icon define the key but set a null value like: 
`'icon' => null`

Answer (score 0):

It happens because there is no element call `icon` in the first array, so if you have to set the default value for non-required elements  just like below

```
DB::beginTransaction();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($privileges); $i++) {
        DB::table('prev_definition')->insert([
            'priv_title' => $privileges[$i]['priv_title'],
            'priv_key' => $privileges[$i]['priv_key'],
            'display_group' => $privileges[$i]['display_group'],
            'parent_id' => $privileges[$i]['parent_id'],
            'type' => $privileges[$i]['type'],
            'icon' => isset($privileges[$i]['icon']) ? $privileges[$i]['icon'] ? null; //set the default as NULL or something else
        ]);
    }
DB::commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create model :

```
php artisan make:model PrevDefinition
```

In model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PrevDefinition extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'prev_definition';

    public $timestamps = true;

    protected $fillable = ['priv_title', 'priv_key', 'display_group', 'parent_id', 'type', 'icon'];
}
```

In seeder:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\PrevDefinition;

class privilegesTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $privileges = [
            ['priv_title' => 'Basic Contact','priv_key' => 'can_access_patient_basic_contact', 'display_group' => 'patient_basic_contact','parent_id' => 7,'type' => 'menu'],
            ['priv_title' => 'Create Task','priv_key' => 'patient_basic_contact_can_add_task', 'display_group' => 'patient_basic_contact','parent_id' => 13,'type' => 'create_task','icon' => 'create_task'],
            ['priv_title' => 'View','priv_key' => 'patient_basic_contact_can_view', 'display_group' => 'patient_basic_contact','parent_id' => 13,'type' => 'view','icon' => 'view'],
            ['priv_title' => 'Edit','priv_key' => 'patient_basic_contact_can_edit', 'display_group' => 'patient_basic_contact','parent_id' => 13,'type' => 'edit','icon' => 'edit'],
            ['priv_title' => 'Delete','priv_key' => 'patient_basic_contact_can_delete', 'display_group' => 'patient_basic_contact','parent_id' => 13,'type' => 'delete','icon' => 'delete'],
        ];

        foreach ($privileges as $data) {
            PrevDefinition::create($data);
        }
    }
}
```